# Combine two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns in excel

```
   A    | B
   ----------
  1     | one
  #N/A  | two
  3     | three
```

I want result from these two columns as:

1 
   two
   3

Please help me to do this.

Comment: it is for other errors also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C1 and copy it down the C column

```
=IFERROR(A1,B1)
```